# I use Broadcast to listen network changed, but receive broadcast in first register

Tags: android, kotlin

I use Broadcast to listen network changed, when I registered network changed broadcast, then I receive the notification in broadcast's `onReceive()` method by launch app firstly, it shows the network has a connection, but my phone's network not changed, It has always network connection.

```
private val mNetWorkChangeReceiver = NetWorkChangeReceiver()

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        register()
    }
   private fun register() {
        val intentFilter = IntentFilter()
        intentFilter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE")
        registerReceiver(mNetWorkChangeReceiver, intentFilter)
    }
 override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        unregisterReceiver(mNetWorkChangeReceiver)
    }
 class NetWorkChangeReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            Log.d("test", "intent action = ${intent!!.action}")
        }

    }
```

I don't know how should I modify?

Comment: This broadcast only work when your device network changes....like your wifi or mobile data switched.

Comment: @AnkushBist But my phone's network doesn't changed, I still receive network changed in first launch app.

Comment: because you registered the broadcastreceiver and that time it receive network on a network

Comment: @AnkushBist I don't understand, how should I modify?

Comment: for the first time it will detect the network at the receiver, that's why you are getting network change notification. But if you do not want to receive the notification for the first time then you can add some status.

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4238921/7948109) for checking `Network Connectivity` of your android device